# position div where mouse clicks and store position in database?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to to position a div where the mouse is clicked inside a parent div.

This works fine as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/7s2mykr9/1/

Now, I store the `top` and `left` values of that div in the MYSQL database.

However, when I get those values back from mysql database and use them for a div on my page, this div is in a different position than where I originally clicked on! and I have no idea why this is happening.

this is how I get the top and left values from mysql and use them in a div inside my page:

```
<div id="parentDiv">
<divstyle="position: absolute; z-index: 1000; width: 40px; height: 40px; border-radius: 50%; text-align: center; left: <?php echo $left; ?>; top: <?php echo $top; ?>">
</div>
</div>
```

is there something i am missing or do i need to change anything?

any help would be appreciated.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Any errors ? Are you providing `px` unit ?

Comment: @RayonDabre, javascript error or php error? I am using the exact code you see in the jsfiddle for positioning the div where I click inside the div.

Comment: `top` and `left` gives you current position on **visible** screen. You have to take `window.scrollTop` into account. How big is the difference in positions? Do you scroll the page before you click?

Comment: @Zealander,  the difference is huge. in fact everything I pull from database goes and sticks to the left corner of the parent div. and no, I don't scroll the page before I click inside the parent div.

Comment: Are ou getting correct values from your `api request`, If yes then there is no way this should not work..

Comment: I assume you don't have this syntax error as you've shown `divstyle`? missing space.

Comment: @Zealander, okay i managed to close difference now by adding a relative position to the wrapper div and removing the position:relative from the parent div. Now, the difference is tiny. is there any way you could explain the window.scrollTop and how I can use it ?

Answer (score 0):

Absolute positioned blocks search for the nearest parent that *has* a position set which I think is the problem you are facing.
Define a position for the `parentDiv` (at least `position:relative`).

Comment: But in JSfiddle `parentDiv` doesn't have any position set.

Comment: yes, but in my own page it does.. sorry for not mentioning it there!